# New Elance ID vs Old one

Tags: attracting-clients

I created Elance ID around three years ago but never used. Now I want to start biding on Elance, Should I go with new ID or using Old one will be better?

Comment: If you try with a new profile, immediately contact Elance support and tell them to delete your other account (I am not sure if you can delete it by yourself). But don't simply create a new profile and do nothing as they may detect that you have 2 accounts and may lock both of you. They are rigid on these kind of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a person who hires freelancers on eLance often, I can tell you that the reviews and ratings you get are what will be looked at. I don't think I've ever considered someone who has no history/reviews, regardless of how long they've been on eLance. I look at the number of jobs completed with the subsequent reviews/rating. One job with a 5-star rating is not as attractive as 45 jobs with a 4-star rating.

With that said, a new eLance profile might be slightly better, in that people may be willing to give you a chance since you're new (thus explaining why you have no history).

Comment: Yes thanks, That is really helpful. Will it be good if I do my first job at $0 so I can get review and ratings for next?